# ORA-00979 Not a Group function error for query with User defined function in select statement

Tags: oracle, plsql, group-by, with-statement

I have this query where a user defined function is added in the select and group by statement.

The inner select query without the WITH clause runs fine and doesn't give any error. But after adding WITH clause it gives the following error -

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
> 00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
> *Cause:
> *Action: Error at Line: 3 Column: 29

I need the WITH clause to return only a subset of the entire result set based on input ranges.

Query is as follows:

```
 WITH INFO AS (
    SELECT 
        GET_EVAULATED_VALUE(T.C_IMP, T.IMP) AS IMPORTANCE,
        count(*) AS NO_OF_PC_AFFECTED 
    FROM TABLE_NAME T 
    WHERE T.ACNT_REL_ID = 16 
        GROUP BY 
        (GET_EVAULATED_VALUE(T.C_IMP, T.IMP))
    ORDER BY IMPORTANCE desc 
)
SELECT * FROM 
( 
    SELECT ROWNUM AS RN,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFO) COUNTS,
    IMPORTANCE
 FROM INFO
)
WHERE RN > 0 AND RN <= 10;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how to use CTE with group by on user defined function. But I realized that I can rewrite the query to remove sub-query and CTE and make it simpler as following (and it works):

```
select * from ( 
    select a.*, ROWNUM rnum from
        (SELECT
            count(*) over() as COUNTS,
            GET_EVAULATED_VALUE(T.C_IMP, T.IMP) AS IMPORTANCE,
            count(*) AS NO_OF_PC_AFFECTED
        FROM TABLE_NAME T 
        WHERE T.ACNT_RELATION_ID = 16
        GROUP BY
            (GET_EVAULATED_VALUE(T.C_IMP, T.IMP))
        ORDER BY importance desc) a
    where ROWNUM <= 10 )
where rnum >= 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here, I created a table "TABLE_CTE" instead of using a CTE and it worked.

```
    CREATE TABLE TABLE_CTE
    AS
    SELECT
        USER_DEFINED_FUNCTION(date_1),
        COUNT(*)
    FROM 
        TABLE_NAME
    GROUP BY 
        USER_DEFINED_FUNCTION(date_1)
    ;
    
    SELECT * FROM TABLE_CTE
```